# reading little endian from binary file into integers in C++

Tags: c++, file, wav, endianness

I am parsing a wav file and slowing it down or speeding it up by a given factor. So I want to read the sample rate and the byte rate from the wave file header and modify it according to the factor. The problem is that they are in little endian.

In C, I can do this

```
inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)
    {
        x = (x>>24) | 
            ((x<<8) & 0x00FF0000) |
            ((x>>8) & 0x0000FF00) |
            (x<<24);
    }
```

and then

```
unsigned int num;
while ( fread(&num, 1, 4,fp) != 0) 
endian_swap(num);
```

but how can I do the same in C++?
I have tried

```
    int length = 4; 
    my_input_file.read(&num, length);
```

but it didn't work because the compiler was expecting a char pointer in the first argument. I am using filestreams everywhere in the code and that's why I cannot just use a file pointer and do it the C way. Any idea how can I do this?

Also, Can I use sscanf to read little-endian formatted data from the binary file into an integer directly?

Comment: @Timo: for reading **binary**?

Comment: @op: read bytes one by one and compute the value. As a bonus, this will work regardless whether your system is bigendian or little endian (opposed to your C sample that would break horribly if run on the wrong system).

Comment: @TedLyngmo fp is a File*

Comment: `length = sizeof(int); my_input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), length);`

Comment: @spectras can you elaborate more?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: better to use `std::int32_t` then, as binary format doesn't depend of target `int` size ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed. i was just about to add: Always use fixed width types when working with binary formats.

Comment: op> Read into a `uint8_t bytes[4]` then compute the result as `bytes[0] + (bytes[1]<<8) + (bytes[2]<<16) + ...)`. Probably extract this into a small function for readability.

Comment: @Jarod42 do stream operators not work on binary? Don't we have `ios_base::binary` for that?

Comment: You might want to use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian to be more portable.

Comment: @DanM.> note that the approach I suggest in my comment is portable across different endiannesses out of the box.

Comment: In C, you cannot do this `inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)`

Comment: @MikeCAT yeah it is in c++, I meant the File* when I referred to C instead of filestreams of C++

Comment: @Jarod42 nvm just tried it

Comment: @Timo `do stream operators not work on binary?` All stream extraction overloads except for `operator>>(basic_streambuf*)` are for formatted input.

Answer (score 1):

> In C, I can do this

Problems with your approach are:

1. It only works if bytes have 8 bits. This is not guaranteed by the C (nor C++).
2. It only works if `usigned int` has 4 bytes. This is not guaranteed by the C (nor C++) standard.
3. Swapping should only be done for little endian input if the CPU is natively big endian. This is not guaranteed by the C (nor C++) standard. <sub>Note that x86 is little endian.</sub>
4. C doesn't have references.

> but how can I do the same in C++?

Besides the issues above, `endian_swap` happens to be valid C++.

In C++, you can use for example this to read a binary file into memory:

```
std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin = is;
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end = {};
std::vector<unsigned char> data(begin, end);
```